# Differntiability of multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $ S\subset\mathbb{R}^{2} $ be the set defined by :

$ S=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}x\\
|x|
\end{pmatrix}:x\in[-1,1]\right\}  $

let $ \gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^{2} $ be a continuous 1-1 function such that $ \gamma\left(a\right)=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\gamma\left(b\right)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\
1
\end{pmatrix} $.

Let $ t_{0}\in[a,b] $ such that

$ \gamma\left(t_{0}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $

I have to prove or disprove:

If $ \gamma $ is differntiable at $ t_0 $ then $ \gamma'\left(t_{0}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $.

I tried to assume for contradiction that $ \gamma $ is diiferentiable at $ t_0 $ and that $ \gamma'\left(t_{0}\right)\neq\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $

But couldnt reach a contradiction. Any ideas would help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you want that $\{\gamma(t),t\in[a,b]\}=S$

**Solution assuming $\gamma$ is differentiable everywhere, which is not true**

If $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))^\intercal$ is differntiable, then both $\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t)$ have derivatives at every point $t\in[a,b]$.

Consider, $\gamma_2(t)$. It is a differentiable function that reaches minimum at $t_0$, since $\gamma_2(t_0)=0$ and $\gamma_2(t)\ge0$ by the construction of set $S$. Thus, $\gamma'_2(t_0)=0$.

Let's assume $\gamma'_1(t_0)\neq0$, then there exists a neighbourhood $U=(t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon)$ where $\gamma_1(t)$ is monotonous. Together with continuity it gives you the invertibility of $\gamma_1(t)$ in $U$, so there is a continuous differentiable function $t=g(\gamma_1)$. However, function $\gamma_2(t)=\gamma_2(g(\gamma_1))=|\gamma_1|$ doesn't have a derivative at $\gamma_1=0, g(\gamma_1)=t_0$ despite being a composition of differentiable functions.

**Solution if $\gamma$ is differentiable only at $t_0$**

There exist $U=(t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)$ and $g(t)$, that
$$\gamma(t_0+h) = \gamma(t_0) + \gamma'(t_0)h + g(h),$$
where $\lim_{h\to 0} |g(h)|/h \to 0$. Assume $|\gamma'(t_0)|=C\neq0$. There exist some $h_0>0$ that both $g(h_0)$ and $g(-h_0)$ are smaller than $h_0C/8$.

Let's denote $a=\gamma(t_0+h)$, $b=\gamma(t_0-h)$, $c=h_0\gamma'(t_0)$. Triangle inequality:

$$
|a| > |c| - |a-c| = |h_0\gamma'(t_0)| - |g(h_0)| = Ch_0 - \frac18Ch_0 = \frac78 Ch_0
$$

Thus, for each point $|\gamma_1|=\gamma_2$: $\gamma_2(t_0+h_0)>Ch_0 7/8\sqrt2 > 0.6 Ch_0$

Another triangle inequality gives us:

$$
|b-(-a)| < |b-(-c)| + |(-c)-(-a)| = |g(-h_0)| + |g(h_0)| < \frac14 Ch_0
$$

In other words:
$$|\gamma_2(t_0-h_0)+\gamma_2(t_0+h_0)| < \frac14 Ch_0$$

Since $\gamma_2(t_0+h_0) > 0$:
$$
\gamma_2(t_0-h_0) < \gamma_2(t_0+h_0) + Ch_0/4 < −0.35 Ch_0.
$$

Which is impossible since $\gamma_2\ge0$

Comment: I didnt mention that $ \gamma $ is differentiable anywhere, only in specific point $t_0$

Comment: Good notice. I added a proper solution.